# Can I destroy a star faster by trapping it in a spherical mirror?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, reflection, stars, stellar-physics

What would happen, if I were to trap the Sun in an almost perfectly reflective spherical mirror? I'm assuming this would accelerate the life of the sun and reduce the timescale required to turn it into a dwarf. How could I roughly estimate this timescale speed-up, if one occurs?

I'm assuming, of course, that the mirror is large enough to fit the sun in any of its giant phases.

Comment: Actually, this question would be more on-topic on https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ . Not that it's off-topic here, it does ask about physics. But the experimental setup would do well in a Sci-Fi novel.

Answer (score 4):

It would reduce the star's ability to cool off the heat it produces in its core, so the star would heat up. As the star heats up, it grows, becoming less dense in the process. **The drop in density reduces the rate of fusion within the star's core**.

As such, you would not destroy the star, but rather conserve it, since it now takes a longer time to burn through its fuel.

---

Actually, this reduction in fusion rate on expansion is precisely what makes stars *self-controlled* fusion reactors. If it were the other way round with fusion gaining speed as density decreases, stars would not be able to form in the first place. They would simply blow up once they are heavy enough to begin fusion.

Comment: Reflecting back a significant fraction of the light emitted by a star would warm it outer shell. The star would expand in volume and being less dense would lower the gravity on the outer shells such that they exert less pressure on the inner core.

Comment: One could use this to cool their star enough allowing for a smaller goldilocks zone and smaller more easily built dyson sphere to encircle it. In fact, the dyson sphere could be held up from expaninding the star such that the pressure inside it supports the dyson sphere.